# Haar Cascade - Why does my trained model think everything is a shoe?

Tags: computer-vision, training-data, haar-classifier

I trained a classifier with the cascade trainer gui. I used about 2000 negative images and 900 positive images of shoes. After training was complete the program produced a file called cascade.xml. I ran opencv python script on multiple images such as picture of library. The results was always hundreds of boxes drawn around any or every thing. I thinks everything is a shoe(if it even knows what a shoe is). I even ran the script with an image of Nike shoe and the classifier drew hundreds of boxes within the shoe image. What might be the case here? My classifier should know enough about a shoe that It doesn't mistake a library as. And why would my classifier be drawing rectangles around everything?

Answer (score 0):

Haar cascades cannot classify objects, unless we tell it to name the objects from that particular cascade. Haar cascades can only draw boxes around objects. cv2.putText(img,'Persons Face',(x-10,y-10), font, 1, (0,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) unless we put that piece of code, you will not get the names of objects. Also what was the size of the training boxes. If it was too small, maybe the lower resolution camera mistakes the objects

Comment: Well I only tested my created cascade on still images. All the drawing would freeze my webcam. The size of the training boxes were small; id say 24x24px. I noticed a few shoes got into my negatives. Could 10 images of shoes in the negative folder change that much?

Comment: "Haar cascades cannot classify objects".. what do you mean? I used shoes to train the model. How haar cascade cant classify it? Haar cascades scans image for an object right?

Comment: Even 1 shoe can have an impact, try to get rid of those 10 shoes and try again. Btw how many stages did you run. Maybe if it was lower the accuracy will not be much. Haar cascade identifies objects, it cannot classify them. Identifying means, identify only a shoe, it can't distinguish between a person or a book or something else,  talking about only1 cascade. I know you can multiple cascades to identify individual objects. That's the only reason i moved to tensorflow

Comment: I used 12 stages. Mind explaining how one shoe could have an impact. I thought linear regression and clustering would just draw a new line to fit the data. I thought having a shoe in the neg set would simply tell the machine that this type of shoe is different than the positive images.

Comment: 12 stages is fairly decent. Haar works by comparing the pos image shoe with the neg images, so it's like making a map of how a shoe would look like in various scenarios. There are a million possibilities  where the show might be present, hence the more p and n images higher the accuracy. Maybe that small amount of shoes in neg images maybe be causing the error. It'd be worth deleting those files and trying again. Btw how do you train your cascade files?

Comment: using the Cascade Trainer GUI for windows. If it fails again going to try using opencv.

Comment: That website has a cascade training app. Check it out. Using it is pretty easy and Youtube has some setup videos too

Comment: I changed my positive images to dogs. Below is my github link where you can view the code. 
The file name is called detect.py. I included a few images of dogs that I trained my model with so you could see what the positive photos generally 
looked like. You can ignore the other xml files such as face and eye. I was using those for testing haar cascade and they work properly. 
The code is set up to load dog.jpg and draw boxes. 
Results.png is a example of what the results are when I feed the program and Image using dog.xml

Github Link : https://github.com/sirShakir/dogCascadeDemo

Comment: I used 1300 positive and 1000 negative images to train the xml. Its still drawing boxes everywhere.

Comment: Actually i did try the gui to train 60 pos and 600 neg images to train shoes, and it works fairly well. It can detect objects in fairly bright conditions. And yeah always happy to help

Comment: hmm how did you get it to work. Ive failed tons of cascades. I am going to try it again but with 60pos and 600neg. Any particular specs you used?

Comment: Nothing fancy, a couple years old laptop took me over6 hours to train lol. My pc is busted collecting funds for a rtx 2070 rig. Must be a huge bump in training speeds

Answer (score 0):

The general rule would be negative images should be more than twice the positive images atleast. Btw how are you training your cascades? Wait let me try to do a dog cascades with 10 images and report back.

Comment: I am using the Cascade Trainer GUI [https://amin-ahmadi.com/cascade-trainer-gui/]. Will try more negative images next time.

Comment: still no luck. I even tried training cascade this method [https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/]

Comment: Do you have a spare usb camera you can hook up and try??

Comment: yea. Tested on 3 different laptops.

Comment: I have abandoned this method. I'm going to try and learn tensorflow to train